# Referencing FormControl elements in a FormArray

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I can't seem to discover the way to reference form controls in my component template.

Although I am passing the form group (from the `<form>` tag) into this child component, I know I have a valid FormGroup object structure, because I can see the raw output from console.log(this.f.getRawValue()):

```
abn:""
addressLine1:""
addressLine2:""
addressLine3:""
addressPostcode:""
addressState:""
addressSuburb:""
contactEmail:""
contactFax:""
contactMobile:""
contactPhone:""
fcApprovals:Array(1)
0:
approvalNumber:""
description:""
expires:Sat Mar 03 2018 17:07:50 GMT+1100 (AEDT) {}
```

This is exactly the object structure I expected coming into the form html

```
<div *ngIf="f.get('fcApprovals')" [formGroup]="f" class="block-container center form-panel not-full-width">

  <div class="panel-title">Approvals</div>
  <div class="block-container center not-full-width" formArrayName="fcApprovals"
       *ngFor="let approval of f.get('fcApprovals').controls; let i = index;">
    <div class="block-element pad-me-up" [formGroupName]="i">

      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
      'has-danger': description.invalid && description.dirty,
      'has-success': description.valid && description.dirty}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="description"
               formControlName="description" required/>

        <div *ngIf="description.untouched || description.valid"
             class="ui message">Description
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="description.dirty || description.touched">
          <div *ngIf="description.errors.required"
               class="ui error message">Description is required
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="icon description"></div>
      </div>
```

The page goes on after this, but the above is what's important. The problem is that the reference "description" is undefined.

I have tried the following referening:

```
i.description
approval.description
fcApprovals[i].description
fcApprovals[i].control.description
```

and many more. Nothing seems to work. The error I get is:

```
ApprovedComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ApprovedComponent.html:8)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14651)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13798)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14149)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14107)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13799)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14149)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14107)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13799)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14149)
```

The error references the FormArray iteration just above the description reference, but the property 'invalid' first appears on description.

So, how do you reference these controls and their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **approval.get('description')**

I happened to stumble across a reference to this in an unrelated post. It's definitely a good candidate for the documentation, because there's no way I would have guessed that!

And the key was in my typescript component.

```
  return this.fb.group({
    'description': ['', Validators.required],
    'approvalNumber': ['', Validators.required],
    'expires': new Date(),
  });
```

I actually put the three controls into a group, so I was iterating a FormArray containing one or more FormGroups - golly!

What's a bit odd though, it appears that the errors object is not on the same path, because:

```
approval.get('description').errors.required
```

returns "Cannot read property 'required' of null"

I've spent about 9 hours on this!